# Convert single column dataframe to dataframe with multiple rows and named columns

Tags: r, dataframe

```
dfOrig <- data.frame(rbind("1",
                       "C",
                       "531404",
                       "3",
                       "B",
                       "477644"))
setnames(dfOrig, "Value")
```

I have a single column vector, which actually comprises two observations of three variables. How do I convert it to a data.frame with the following structure:

```
ID      Code     Tag
"1"     "C"      "531404"
"3"     "B"      "477644"
```

Obviously, this is just a toy example to illustrate a real-world problem with many more observations and variables.

Comment: So you will have to create more columns than just `ID`, `Code`, and `Tag`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's another approach - it does rely on the `dfOrig` column being ordered 1,2,3,1,2,3 etc.

```
x <- c("ID", "Code", "Tag")    # new column names
n <- length(x)                 # number of columns
res <- data.frame(lapply(split(as.character(dfOrig$Value), rep(x, nrow(dfOrig)/n)), 
         type.convert))
```

The resulting data is:

```
> str(res)
#'data.frame':  2 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ Code: Factor w/ 2 levels "B","C": 2 1
# $ ID  : int  1 3
# $ Tag : int  531404 477644
```

As you can see, the column classes have been converted. In case you want the `Code` column to be `character` instead of `factor` you can specify `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in the `data.frame` call.

And it looks like this:

```
> res
#  Code ID    Tag
#1    C  1 531404
#2    B  3 477644
```

Note: You have to get the column name order in `x` in line with the order of the entries in `dfOrig$Value`.

If you want to get the column order of `res` as specified in `x`, you can use the following:

```
res <- res[, match(x, names(res))]
```

Comment: Excellent, Is there a way to add the column headers (ID, Code, Tag) at the same time?

Comment: use colnames(df) <- c("ID", "Code","Tag")

Comment: Columns sorted into alphabetical order (Code, ID, Tag) - need original (ID, Code, Tag)?

Comment: @matekus, you can use `res[, match(x, names(res))]` or whatever logic / order you like

Answer (score 1):

Maybe convert to matrix with nrow:

```
# set number of columns
myNcol <- 3

# convert to matrix, then dataframe
res <- data.frame(matrix(dfOrig$Value, ncol = myNcol, byrow = TRUE),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# convert the type and add column names
res <- as.data.frame(lapply(res, type.convert),
                     col.names = c("resID", "Code", "Tag"))
res
#   resID Code    Tag
# 1     1    C 531404
# 2     3    B 477644
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `seq`uence of numbers

```
x <- seq(1:nrow(dfOrig)) %% 3  #you can change this 3 to number of columns you need

data.frame(ID = dfOrig$Value[x == 1], 
           Code = dfOrig$Value[x == 2], 
           Tag = dfOrig$Value[x == 0])


#ID Code    Tag
#1  1    C 531404
#2  3    B 477644
```

---

Another approach would be `split`ting the dataframe according to the sequence generated above and then binding the columns using `do.call`

```
x <- seq(1:nrow(dfOrig))%%3
res <- do.call("cbind", split(dfOrig,x))
```

You can definitely change the column names

```
colnames(res) <- c("Tag", "Id", "Code")

#  Tag       Id  Code
#3 531404     1     C
#6 477644     3     B
```